# Gitlab - Runner - Exit status 1

Tags: javascript, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

New to gitlab. Trying to setup basic runner to build a javascript web app. But keep getting this error code and I can't get it to give me any more information on the failure.

```js
ubuntu@********:/home/gitlab-runner/builds/bd82d0d6/0/${username}/${projectname}$ gitlab-runner --debug exec shell build-site
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux revision=96b34cc version=9.5.1
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.1 (96b34cc)
  on  ()
Shell configuration: environment: []
dockercommand:
- sh
- -c
- "if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/bash --login\nelif [
  -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/bash --login\nelif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then\n\texec
  /bin/bash --login\nelif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/sh
  --login\nelif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/sh --login\nelif [ -x /bin/sh
  ]; then\n\texec /bin/sh --login\nelse\n\techo shell not found\n\texit 1\nfi\n\n"
command: bash
arguments:
- --login
passfile: false
extension: ""
  job=1 project=0
Using Shell executor...
Waiting for signals...                              job=1 project=0
Running on ip-10-214-239-156...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/bd82d0d6/0/${username}/${project}/builds/0/project-0'...
done.
Checking out 69fe5296 as HEAD...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ npm install --verbose --debug
Running after script...
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
FATAL: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake. Bad install of node/npm on gitlab machine. Using nvm and setting default node version fixes the issue.

Still odd that the message was not `command npm not found`